# Discretizing a mathematical equation

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, recreational-mathematics, nonlinear-analysis

[image]

This is a 3D map that maps every $(x,y,z)\to (x',y',z')$ uniquely. If i want to implement it's discrete counterpart on  matlab platform, i do the following 
   $$\text{if} (i<=\dfrac{n}{2}  \wedge j\leq \dfrac{n}{2})$$
          \begin{eqnarray*}
       x'=2\cdot (i-1)+1\\
       y'=2\cdot (j-1)+1\\
       z'= \lfloor 0.25\cdot(k-\mod(k-1,2))\rfloor+1; 
\end{eqnarray*}
The input to discretized equatin are integers and the output should also be integers that is why i have used the floor function and since the function is part of some algorithm that involves indexing that starts from $(1,1)$ ex Matlab that is why the $mod$  function is used.
But this is clearly not a unique mapping because $(1,1,1)\to (1,1,1), (1,1,2)\to (1,1,1), (1,1,3)\to (1,1,1), (1,1,4)\to (1,1,1)$. So there has to be some minor adjustments or major ajdustments in the discretizing part that retains the uniqueness of the equation. Can somebody suugest ?

Edit: After the answer: I have added the code where $n=36$, but still it is not giving the unique mapping.

Comment: Please, don't use images as main content of your post. This makes your question impossible to search and inaccessible to the visually impaired. Please transcribe text and mathematics (note that you can [use LaTeX](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/)) and don't forget to give proper attribution to your sources. Avoid using $*$ to denote multiplication as it typically denotes other operations in mathematics (e.g., convolution); use `\cdot` instead).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution assumes $n$ is a multiple of $4$. Let $\def\1{{\bf 1}}\1[S]$ be a function which is equal to $1$ if the statement $S$ is true, and zero otherwise. This is a bijective mapping from the set of ordered tuples $(x,y,z)$ where each $x,y,z\in \{1,2,\dots,n\}$ to itself. 
$$
\begin{align}
x'&=\text{mod}(2(x-1),n)+1+\1[\text{mod}(z,4)= 2\text{ or }\text{mod}(z,4)=0]
\\
y'&=\text{mod}(2(y-1),n)+1+\1[\text{mod}(z,4)= 3\text{ or }\text{mod}(z,4)=0]
\\
z'&=\lceil z/4\rceil + (n/4)\Big(\1[n/2<x] + 2\cdot \1[n/2<y]\Big)
\end{align}
$$

Brief explanation:

The $\text{mod}(2(x-1),n)+1$ part simultaneously captures the $2x$ and $2x-1$ parts of the original, similarly for the $y$.

The original problem works for continuous space, where stretching and compressing is bijective. In the discrete space, when you stretch by a factor of $2$ you leave gaps, and when you compress you get collisions. We simultaneously fix both of these problems with the $\1[n/4< z\le n/2\;\;\text{ or }\;\;3n/4< z\le n]$ and $\1[n/2 <z \le n]$ parts. Essentially, when you try to compress the $z$ part by $4$, you need to instead divide the column into four parts and move some of these parts slightly out of the way.

The expression for $z$ just captures the $z'=z/4 +\{0,1/4,1/2\text{ or }3/4\}$ all in one go.

Comment: Can you explain the equivalence of your answer with the given mathematical equation or just hint the main part?

Comment: @Upstart See edits.

Comment: That was some reasoning,  a doubt : in that $z'$ term what is that $+$ in the middle $+2\mathbf{1}$ does this mean AND?

Comment: @Upstart No, it means addition. We have ${{\bf 1}}[n/2<x]$; this is a number which is equal to $0$ or $1$. Next we have ${{\bf 1}}[n/2<y]$; this is another number which is $0$ or $1$. We multiply the second number by two, then add ($+$) the two numbers together.

Comment: I have added the code that i implemented using your discretized equations, but it is still not giving the unique results, i guess there is something missing in my code, can you have a look?

Comment: @Upstart What is a specific example of $n$ and $(i,j,k)$ and $(i',j',k')$ for which your code mapped $(i,j,k)$ and $(i',j',k')$ to the same place?

Comment: for $n=4$ it is working, but as soon as $n>4$ let's say $8$ , then $(1,1,1) \to (1,1,1)$ and $(1,1,2)\to (1,1,1)$. Actually the mapping you have given  is a $n/4$ to $1 $  mapping

Comment: @Upstart I now see my mistake; the question has been edited and fixed.

Comment: $\text{mod} (z,4)=4$? did you mean $0$? Then your explaination part also needs some editing but anyways yes its working now